# How can I find what questions SO closes?

Tags: discussion, so

I was trying to figure out what the bar is for closing questions on SO, but ran into the rather dumb thing that the search on SO for "closed" doesn't actually pull up a list of closed questions.  Similarly, googling "site:stackoverflow closed" doesn't give me a list of closed questions either.  Is there any easy way for me to find out what sort of questions get closed on SO?

I know this is a little off-topic here, but I'm trying to better understand what SO's policy is so that I can have a non-MO model for how to deal with bad questions.

Comment: This kind of question really belongs on http://meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Yes, I realized it would also be appropriate there, but I figured that I wasn't the only person here who would want to know the answer, since it's been a point of argument here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When searching using stackoverflow, put 'closed:1' in your search.

Answer (score 0):

stackoverflow is not necessarily the model you want. We might hope that this site could settle some definitional questions at the outset and not have quite so much need to be battling about what to close.